# updating a column without losing values

Tags: mysql

I have a table TEST, which has a column TESTCOLUMN in which DEFAULT was = [0, 0, 0]
I have already recorded the values of some users in it: [1, 1, 0] [0, 1, 0] etc
But I need to replace the values with new ones DEFAULT = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
And so that the values in the column accept the new DEFAULT, but retain their values until:
[1, 1, 0] -> [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 0] - > [0, 1, 0, 0, 0] etc

I searched for a similar question, but didn't find an answer. Everywhere a solution is proposed to simply update the default values, but then the values that I currently have will most likely disappear.
How can this be implemented without losing and resetting user data to a new default?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055 #5 and #3

Comment: You need in 2 separate queries. ALTER TABLE which wil set new DEFAULT, and UPDATE which will set new values.